# jQuery target generic class item but unique href with trigger click

Tags: javascript, jquery, hash, triggers

I am trying to target a generic item class with a unique href value based on if hash value is appended to the url unload I want to emulate the click that would normally happen on the page.

jQuery:

```
if(window.location.hash) {
    var hash = window.location.hash;
    function showHashVideo() {
        jQuery("a.btn").attr("href", hash).trigger('click');
    }
    jQuery(showHashVideo);
}
```

HTML:

```
<a class="btn btn-mini" href="#help-video-modal-Graphing" data-url="video-url" data-title="Graphing">Watch Video</a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can read you want to find elements HREF which matches an A element. You can do this:

```
jQuery("a.btn[href='" + hash + "']").trigger("click");
```

This will trigger a click on the `a.btn` with the `href=hash`.

Comment: Hi, the click event doesn't seem to happen. When the page loads it just shows it being the same state.

Comment: i had to target the button's wrapper div and then append the function that does the reload of the page to the end of this query but it did end up working. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

jQuery trigger will not trigger DOM event clicks, so you must do this.

```
jQuery("a.btn").attr("href", hash).get(0).click()
```

You need to use [Attribute-Equals-Selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) `jQuery( "[attribute='value']" )`

```
jQuery('a.btn[href="' + hash + '"]').get(0).click();
```

Comment: +1 even i disagree regarding `don't wrap it with jQuery`, depending where/when snippet is called. If you don't wrap it with `jQuery`, then DOM could be not fully loaded

Comment: @A.Wolff Just noticed that it works calling a function like that :P. I'll remove that

Comment: This is changing all of the buttons on the page to be the hash values. I am looking to grab the hash value from the url and then onload of the page emulate clicking that button on the page which will load that video as if i had clicked it..

Comment: @esternle Oh i see, then it's a mix between my answer and Niels, i'll update the answer soon

Comment: Hi, doesn't seem to trigger the click on page load. Has an error: TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'jQuery('a.btn[href="' + hash + '"]').get(0).click')